# How to change a Boolean argument in the initializer so it becomes true if there is an argument and stays false if there isn't in Python3.6?

Tags: python, class, initialization, arguments

For my assignment I am having trouble when the assignment is asking: 
modify your initializer to include an optional third (boolean) argument that specifies whether request IDs should be included. This is so the function send_message_by_character can act accordingly to the Boolean.

This is what I go so far for the initializer:

```
class UDPClient: 
    def __init__(self, host, port, use_ids = False):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to change that to true and using it in the next function within the class:

```
def send_message_by_character(self, data):
    if use_ids == False:
        #some code
    else:
        #some other code
```

How am I supposed to properly achieve this?

Comment: attach the flag to the instance, i.e `self.use_ids = use_ids` then act on it in `send_message..` by checking `if self.use_ids: ..`

Comment: make it an *instance variable*, the way you normally share state in a class.

Comment: Does it automatically turn to true if there is an argument? Not sure if I have to add a line of code to make it true or not.

Comment: .... You know, it would be *really* simply to test this out yourself. `def f(x=False): print(x)` then try `f()` and `f(True)`

Comment: Thanks this is my first time doing Python so I am trying to still figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the argument `use_ids` a class variable so that you can reference it using any class method:

```
class UDPClient(): 
    def __init__(self, host, port, use_ids = False):
        self.use_ids = use_ids
        ...
```

Now you can reference this variable in the method you made:

```
def send_message_by_character(self, data):
    if self.use_ids == False:
        #some code
    else:
        #some other code
```